# alert() when div content changes using mutationobserver

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

i would like make a script (javascript) that check if the content of a div changes (by ajax, so without refresh the page) and then shows an alert() message.
I think i can use mutation observer but i can't understand how to do it...
The script must re-check the page every 60 second.
Thanks for the help.

```js
//now create our observer and get our target element
var observer = new MutationObserver(fnHandler),
        elTarget = document.querySelector(".w-portfolio-table-body"),
        objConfig = {
            childList: true,
            subtree : true,
            attributes: true, 
            characterData : true
        };

//then actually do some observing
observer.observe(elTarget, objConfig);

function fnHandler () {
    alert("DETECTED_VARIATION");
}
```

***NOTE: This code is for a chrome extension, so i can't use onchange event :(***

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand? Where are you stuck? I assume you read some documentation, which part is unclear?

Comment: Can you share your code with us what you have tried ???

Comment: Here read... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Sorry, now i have insert the code in the first post. I would like, when content mutate , view the message "DETECTED_VARIATION"...thanks for  the help

Answer (score 4):

First, you should not use your event handler to insert a new element (h2 here), or else you'll end up with an infinite loop.

Second, you need to bind your handler to the observer.

For example:

```
function fnHandler () {
  alert("DETECTED_VARIATION");
}
var observer = new MutationObserver(fnHandler);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/drLrd9w5/1/

Comment: I appreciate very much your help but the script  doesn't work. There is  something wrong.
I'll explain. I have to scan a page with a chrome extension until a text in a div changes by ajax, so no refresh page. I do not know when it changes, so the extension have to always listen. Once detected the change, the extension should write a message [alert();] and then return listening. I really need this script, so I can pay about 5$ who will help me.  (I do not know if I can ask, if not sorry)

Comment: I tried again, and my demo works fine. Are you using a browser that supports mutation observers?

Comment: sorry, I have not explained well. Your script works fine, but my script (based on your) doesn't work. my script have to check if value changes automatically with ajax, not by pressing a button. Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe post your updated code? Whether it's ajax or a button should not make a difference.

Comment: Code updated on the first post. I think the code don't listen DOM mutation...maybe i must use setinterval() to check mutation every x seconds? ps: i have put this code in background,js file of my chrome extension. Is it correct?

Comment: Your code looks correct, but it's hard to tell without context. Make sure your query selector is correct and your ajax actually modifies the selected element.

Comment: in reality the class .w-portfolio-table-body belongs to a div that contains the text that will insert by ajax (in another div). I mean: <div class="w-portfolio-table-body"><div id="random_code">1 text</div><div id="random_code">2 text</div></div> ...i cannot know the name of the id of each div...but this should not be a problem, right?

Comment: Right, this should work. So maybe the issue is with your ajax not inserting the div...

Comment: The ajax works fine (i am making a chrome extension not for my website)... i think someting wrong in the extension...it's possible that the extension don't listen without setinterval() to check every x second??